# Create a new column for table B based on information from table A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this problem. I want to create a report that keeps everything in table B, but adds another column from table A (QtyRecv).

Condition: If RunningTotalQtyUsed (from table B) < QtyRecv, take that QtyRecv for the new column.

For example, for item A1, (RunningTotalQtyUsed) 55 < 100 (QtyRecv), -> ExpectedQtyRecv = 100.

But if RunningTotalQtyUsed exceeds QtyRecv, we take the next QtyRecv to cover that used quantity.

For example, 101 > 100, -> ExpectedQtyRecv = 138.

149 (RunningTotalQtyUsed) < (100 + 138) (QtyRecv) -> get 138.

250 < (100 + 138 + 121) -> get 121.

The same logic applies to item A2.

If total QtyRecv = 6 + 4 + 10 = 20, but RunningTotalQtyUsed = 31 -> result should be 99999 to notify an error that QtyRecv can't cover QtyUsed.

Table A:

```
Item     QtyRecv
A1        100
A1        138
A1        121
A2        6
A2        4
A2        10
```

Table B:

```
Item    RunningTotalQtyUsed
A1        55
A1        101
A1        149
A1        250
A2        1
A2        5
A2        9
A2        19
A2        31
```

Expected result:

```
Item    RunningTotalQtyUsed    ExpectedQtyRecv
A1            55                100
A1            101               138
A1            149               138
A1            250               121
A2            1                  6
A2            5                  6
A2            9                  4
A2            19                 10
A2            31                99999
```

What I made an effort:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM tableB b LEFT JOIN tableA a
ON b.item = a.item 

item    RunningTotalQtyUsed
A1              55
A1              55
A1              55
A1              101
A1              101
A1              101
A1              149
A1              149
A1              149
A1              250
A1              250
A1              250
A2              1
A2              1
A2              1
A2              5
A2              5
A2              5
A2              9
A2              9
A2              9
A2              19
A2              19
A2              19
A2              31
A2              31
A2              31
```

It doesn't keep the same number of rows as table B. How to still keep table B but add the ExpectQtyRecv from table A? Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: *"It doesn't keep the same number of rows as table B."* you have a many to many relationship here; of course you're going to get more rows. You `JOIN` joins *all* the rows in `TableA` with a value of `A1` in `item` to *all* the rows in `TableB` with a value of `A1` in `item` , and  many relationship here; of course you're going to get more rows. You `JOIN` joins *all* the rows in `TableA` with a value of `A2` in `item` to *all* the rows in `TableB` with a value of `A2` in `item`. This gives `(3 * 4) + (3*5)` rows (28 rows).

Comment: With the 2 columns in each table you have, what you want is impossible. There is nothing, for example, to denote the order of your data in `TableA`

Comment: @Lanu, thank you for your comment. If that is the case, can we get the total QtyRecv for each item? For example, from table A, total QtyRecv for A1 is (100+138+121) = 359, total QtyRecv for A2 is  (6 + 4+ 10) = 20. From expected result, column ExpectedTotalQtyRecv is 359 for every A1's row and 20 for A2. Can we do that? Thank you!

Comment: You can `SUM` the values, sure. I would *hope* you know how to do that.#

Comment: @Larnu, this is what I did and get the exact output that I want, but only in this simple case. SELECT DISTINCT b.*, c.MAXX
FROM testB b 
 OUTER APPLY
 (SELECT MAX(QtyRecv) OVER(PARTITION BY a.item) AS MAXX 
 FROM testA a
 WHERE b.item = a.item) c

Comment: A windowed `MAX` in the subquery seems wrong.

Comment: How do you know which TableA row goes with each TableB row?  Also, how do you know in what order the matching TableA rows are supposed to be applied to you new TableB column? (Keep in mind that SQL table rows have no inherent order of their own).

Comment: In a table that contains more than 100k - 500k rows, it takes more than 30 minutes to get the result. However, the final output is not in order. It messed up everywhere and took long time to execute the query successfully :(

Comment: @Lanu, I'm sorry I didn't explain better. I used MAX because I used Window Function on the table A to get Running Total qty for each item, then get the MAX. SELECT SUM(QtyRecv) OVER(PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW AS QtyRecv. Then use MAX from here.

Comment: @RBarryYoung yeah you're right. Your questions actually drive me crazy. I tried using many kinds of JOIN but it keeps messing up the order. I don't really know how to keep the order of table B and add a new customized column based on values from table A.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT B.TOTAL,B.SUM_RunningTotalQtyUsed,A.SUM_QtyRecv   FROM
 (
   SELECT B.ITEM,SUM(B.RunningTotalQtyUsed)AS SUM_RunningTotalQtyUsed
   FROM TABLE_B AS B
   GROUP BY B.ITEM
 )B_TOTAL
 LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT A.ITEM,SUM(A.QtyRecv)AS SUM_QtyRecv
    FROM TABLE_A AS A
    GROUP BY A.ITEM
 )A_TOTAL ON B.ITEM=A.ITEM
```

I can not be sure, but may be you need something like above ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but not what I want. Also, the code has some error. I re-write it like this  SELECT B_TOTAL.SUM_RunningTotalQtyUsed,A_TOTAL.SUM_QtyRecv   FROM
 (
   SELECT B.ITEM,SUM(B.RunningTotalQtyUsed)AS SUM_RunningTotalQtyUsed
   FROM testB AS B
   GROUP BY B.ITEM
 )B_TOTAL
 LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT A.ITEM,SUM(A.QtyRecv)AS SUM_QtyRecv
    FROM testA AS A
    GROUP BY A.ITEM
 )A_TOTAL ON B_TOTAL.ITEM=A_TOTAL.ITEM